# 'The system cannot find the file specified' error on Owin after loading the project from tfs to a different path

Tags: asp.net, tfs

I have a project which was running in localhost without any issues. For some purpose I had to load the project to a different location from TFS. When I try to run it after changing the path I am getting an error as

**Could not load file or assembly 'Owin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

I have tried adding the following code segment as per reading this [article](https://forums.asp.net/t/2111286.aspx?Could+not+load+file+or+assembly+Microsoft+Owin+or+one+of+its+dependencies+The+located+assembly+s+manifest+definition+does+not+match+the+assembly+reference+Exception+from+HRESULT+0x80131040+) but still got the same response.

```
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" 
culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

I have also checked the reference path. It is also referencing the correct path.

I am using `Microsoft.Owin` , `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`, `Microsoft.Owin.Security` in my references.

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For some purpose I had to load the project to a different location from TFS.

Do you mean you pull the code from TFS to different location and build the project with Visual Studio, then you got that error?

If yes, first, please make sure you do not check the `/packages` folder into the source control.

Then use the NuGet command line in the **Package Manager Console**:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

to force reinstall the package references into project.

If above not help you, please share the `HintPath` of the package `Microsoft.Owin` in the project file `.csproj` and the path of the `\packages` folder and `.sln` file

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly. I tried re-installing it from nugget and it worked. Thank you for your reply.